# python Code show invalid syntax (folder_name = 'ebert_reviews')

Tags: python, python-3.x, get

I am try to run python code. but it shows invalid syntax (folder_name = 'ebert_reviews')

the Code

```
import requests
 import os
     ebert_review_urls = ['https://d17h27t6h515a5.cloudfront.net/topher/2017/September/59ad9900_1-the-wizard-of-oz-1939-film/1-the-wizard-of-oz-1939-film.txt',
                             'https://d17h27t6h515a5.cloudfront.net/topher/2017/September/59ad9901_2-citizen-kane/2-citizen-kane.txt']
    
    
    folder_name = 'ebert_reviews'
if not os.path.exists(folder_name):
os.makedirs(folder_name)

for url in ebert_review_urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    with open(os.path.join(folder_name, url.split('/')[-1]) = 'wb')
    as file:
    file.write(response.content)
os.listdir(folder_name)
```

Comment: ['1-the-wizard-of-oz-1939-film.txt', '2-citizen-kane.txt'], is this the output that you want?

Comment: Please fix your indentation. This would generate _several_ `IndentationError`s. We can't be expected to guess at which errors are relevant and which are typos.

Comment: thanks a lot, Chris. that was a good hint.

Comment: thanks for the solution Francisco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem that I found was " = 'wb'"; so put a comma instead:

```py
import requests
import os

ebert_review_urls = [
    'https://d17h27t6h515a5.cloudfront.net/topher/2017/September/59ad9900_1-the-wizard-of-oz-1939-film/1-the-wizard-of-oz-1939-film.txt',
    'https://d17h27t6h515a5.cloudfront.net/topher/2017/September/59ad9901_2-citizen-kane/2-citizen-kane.txt']

folder_name = 'ebert_reviews'
if not os.path.exists(folder_name):
    os.makedirs(folder_name)

for url in ebert_review_urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    with open(os.path.join(folder_name, url.split('/')[-1]), 'wb') as file:
        file.write(response.content)

print(os.listdir(folder_name))
```

Comment: the  output should be like this: ['1-the-wizard-of-oz-1939-film/1-the-wizard-of-oz-1939-film.txt', '2-citizen-kane/2-citizen-kane.txt']

Comment: the output should be for the two links